# Asymptotic lower bound for R(k,k)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, asymptotics, ramsey-theory

I'm reading Spencer's lectures on the probabilistic method.  Using the Lovasz local lemma, we've shown that $R(k,k)>n$ if 
$$
4{k \choose 2} {n \choose k-2} 2^{1-{k \choose 2}} < 1.
$$

Now I'm trying to analyze the asymptotics:
$$
2k^2 \frac{(ne/k)^{k-2}}{\sqrt{2\pi(k-2)}}2^{1-k^2/2}<1
\\
n\sim \frac{k}{e} 2^{-(2-k^2/2)/(k-2)}=\frac{2}{e}k2^{k/2}.
$$

However, Spencer (without explanation) says $n\sim \frac{\sqrt{2}}{e}k2^{k/2}$.  Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from replacing $\binom{k}{2}$ with $k^2/2$. Leave it as $k(k-1)/2$.

Then the exponent on the 2, after dividing by $k-2$ becomes $${\frac{k(k-1)}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{k-2}}= (\frac{k}{2}-\frac{1}{2})\cdot(1 +\frac{2}{k} + O(1/k^2)) = \frac{k}{2} + \frac 12 + o(1).$$
If you do Erd\H{o}s's original argument and leave $\binom{k}{2}$ as $k(k-1)/2$ you will see where the $\sqrt{2}$ in the denominator comes from.

Comment: Thanks!  I always have a hard time recognizing what to keep and what to throw away.