# Lower bound for diagonal Ramsey numbers

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, ramsey-theory

In the book "The Probabilistic Method" by Alon and Spencer there is a quite clear derivation (provided by Lovasz local lemma) of the fact, that if $ e\binom{k}{2}\binom{n-2}{k-2}\cdot 2^{1-\binom{k}{2}}<1 $, then $ R(k,k)>n $. Then authors write that "a short computation shows that this gives" $ R(k,k)>(\sqrt{2}/e)(1+o(1))k2^{k/2} $. To be honest, I completely don't understand how to prove it, because it seems that use of asymptotic equivalence will spoil initial inequality. I've seen the post ([Asymptotic lower bound for R(k,k)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541145/asymptotic-lower-bound-for-rk-k)), but I'm not sure that it answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $n>2k$, we have 
  $$ \binom{n-2}{k-2} < \binom n{k-2} < \left( \frac{en}{k-2} \right)^{k-2} < e^2\left( \frac{en}{k} \right)^{k-2}, $$
where the middle (well-known) estimate follows from
  $$ \binom nm < \frac{n^m}{m!} = \left(\frac nm\right)^m \frac{m^m}{m!} < \left(\frac nm\right)^m \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{m^j}{j!} = \left( \frac{en}{m} \right)^m. $$
Therefore,
  $$ e \binom k2 \binom{n-2}{k-2} 2^{1-\binom k2} 
                          < e^3 k^2 \left( \frac{en}{k} 2^{-(k+1)/2} \right)^{k-2}. $$
It follows that if, say, 
  $$ 2k < n < (\sqrt 2/e)k2^{k/2}(1-1/\log k), \tag{$\ast$} $$
then 
  $$ e \binom k2 \binom{n-2}{k-2} 2^{1-\binom k2} < e^3 k^2 \left( 1-\frac1{\log k}\right)^{k-2} < e^3k^2 e^{-(k-2)/\log k} <1, $$
implying $R(k,k)>n$. The estimate in question is now obtained by choosing $n$ to be the largest integer in the range ($\ast$).

Comment: Thanks for answer! Actually, I have a couple of questions about your proof. Firstly, why in the third inequality you write $ 2^{-(k+1)/2} $ instead of $ 2^{-(k-1)/2} $? It seems to me that $ 2^{-(k-1)/2}>2^{-(k+1)/2} $. And secondly, after substitution of $ n $ in initial inequality I get $ ek^2(1-1/\log{k})^k<1$, what is unclear to me.

Comment: @Kumquat: You are right about $(k-1)/2$ vs $(k+1)/2$; I have fixed this. Concerning $1-1/\log k$ term - it is not uniquely defined; anyway, I explained why it works as it is.

Comment: Actually, there is a difference between $ 1-1/\log{k} $ and $ 2+1/\log{k} $, because second expression isn't equal to $ 1+o(1) $. I didn't quite understand what you have done now, in my opinion, everything worked if you would replace $(k+1)/2 $ by $ (k-1)/2 $ and $ 1-1/\log{k} $ by $ 2+1/\log{k} $. But anyway the problem is solved.

Comment: @Kumquat: the difference between $(k+1)/2$ and $(k-1)/2$ is in fact important, it has to do with the fact that we deal with the binomial coefficient $\binom{n-2}{k-2}$, not $\binom{n-2}k$.  As to $1-1/\log k$, we need $n<(\sqrt 2/e)k2^{k/2}b$, where $b$ is chosen to satisfy $b^{k-2}\le 1/(e^2k^2)$. There are, of course, infinitely many ways to choose such $b$, one choice being $1-1/\log k$. ($b=2+1/\log k$ does *not* work BTW).

Comment: Really? I thought that we threw out $ \binom{n-2}{k-2} $ in the first estimation. After replacing $ (k+1)/2 $ by $ (k-1)/2 $  we get $ n<(e/\sqrt{2})k2^{k/2}b $, but that's OK, since $ b=2+1/\log{k}=2(1+1/(2\log{k})) $ and $ 2/\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2} $.

Comment: @Kumquat: In the first displayed chain of inequalities, we have $k-2$ in the exponent in the RHS; this is stronger than having the exponent $k$, which would only give the eventual bound $(1+o(1))(1/e\sqrt2)k2^{k/2}$, instead of the stronger bound $(1+o(1))(\sqrt 2/e)k2^{k/2}$. And, **you cannot take $b=2+1/\log k$**, recheck your argument!

Comment: OK, I found a mistake in my calculations. But last inequality in your proof looks wrong (at least for small $ k $).

Comment: @Kumquat: right! However, since we are after an asymptotic bound (the $o(1)$-term), we have all the rights to assume that $k$ is large.

Comment: It also seems to me that inequality
$$ \left( \frac{en}{k-2} \right)^{k-2} < e\left( \frac{en}{k} \right)^{k-2} $$ 
is wrong. Especially for large $ k $.

Comment: @Kumquat: My bad - but this is very easy to correct, will do in a minute.